# I am unable to open in Files ->Devices ->139GB volume and 73GB volume

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to open 139GB volume and 73GB volume in files. I am using UNUNTU 14.04.
Why am I getting the following error:

```
Unable to access “139 GB Volume”
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/admin123/9CC66C3CC66C1932: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/admin123/9CC66C3CC66C1932"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 14: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: Did you shutdown Windows correctly?

Comment: yes i shutdown it correctly

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Use edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open terminal and run this.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

NTFS-3G is a stable, full-featured, read-write NTFS driver for Linux,

then run this command on the terminal to fix your NTFS partition. Replace XY with your partion name (sda4) - (Then the command for your partition is -- sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4)

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/XY
```

Comment: pls also I am not able to open 73GB volume in Files:            Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/admin123/0C28738D28737494: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/admin123/0C28738D28737494"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: you can always use the above command on any drive. just replace XY with your partition name.. You can find the name in the error message too..  The name should be -- sdxx-- format..  ex-- sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1

Comment: for 73Gb volume i tried with sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1,then getting below error in terminal:        Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted